# Ruby: File.open odd behavior with variable as name of file

Tags: ruby, file

Ruby Noob Here!
I'm trying to create and write to files in ruby using variables as the name of the files to be created.  If I use a type the file name it work same with another variable #{system}, but the issue appears to be with a specific variable that is parsed early on.
Error received- Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

```
array#record contains: 
Sun /log/schedule.log.20180617
Mon /log/schedule.log.20180618  
Tue /log/schedule.log.20180619
Wed /log/schedule.log.20180620
Wed /log/schedule.log
```

Section of code.

```
lines = record.split("\n")
lines.each do |line|
    log = /(\/.*schedule.log(?:\.20[0-9]{6})?)/.match(line)
    @cmd = "grep DEBUG #{log} | grep \"start\\|running\""
    rawdata = ssh.exec!(@cmd) 
    logfile = File.new("#{system}_#{log}", 'w+')
       logfile.puts rawdata
    logfile.close
end
ssh.close
```

OUTPUT
Error received- Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - server1_schedule.log

Desired output should create a handful of log files with the naming convention `<persystem_schedule.log<date>>`.

Comment: Is that the literal error you get? ENOENT usually means a file or directory doesn't exist, for example if you try to create `foo/bar` when `foo` doesn't exist.

Comment: I suggest you maybe can post a piece of code that people can run, it's easier to get help. Even if somebody can find any bug just by reading.

Comment: iGian -  The section of code is the actual piece of code.  I've added the values for the "record" array to make it easier for people to run the code, simply because this section of code is part of 100+ lines of code. It was already narrowed down the datatype for the "log" variable.  Somehow when we are using matchData it's no longer a string.  I've attempted to convert the datatype back to a string using .to_s , but it still did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're not giving sufficient information to solve the problem, but in these cases I find that it's often helpful to simplify the code; doing so often reveals other issues.

Is there a reason you're using the File `open`, `puts`, and `close`? This adds a lot of complexity which I think is unnecessary, and that complexity may be masking some other problem. I recommend changing this:

```
rawdata = ssh.exec!(@cmd) 
logfile = File.new("#{system}_#{log}", 'w+')
logfile.puts rawdata
logfile.close
```

to something like this:

```
File.write("#{system}_#{log}", ssh.exec!(@cmd))
```

and see if the result changes or if it reveals a different problem.

Comment: Keith, Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately the air-gapped system doesn't support File.write.  
undefined method 'write' for File:Class

Comment: File.write has been part of the standard distribution of Ruby for many, many years. Is your Ruby system modified, and, if so, by whom, and it what way? I don't think it even makes sense to remove `File.write` for security reasons because the same thing can be accomplished in other ways. Are you modifying the File class yourself?

Comment: great questions.  I'm not sure if the system was modified nor whom built the system.  I just inherited all ruby tasks because of my perl background. I can tell you that the "log" is not a string datatype.  The matchdata is doing some sort of voodoo that I can't even convert back to a string using the .to_s method.

Comment: I suggest reinstalling Ruby. I like `rvm`, it makes doing so very easy, and you can do it in your user space so that superuser access is not required. Google `install rvm` for easy instructions.

Comment: Regarding the data types of `log` and `matchdata`, I think your confusion is due to the fact that you may not be aware that when you use string interpolation (`#{}`) in a double quoted string, Ruby calls `to_s` on the value of the expression. So matchdata never *was* a string; Ruby was calling `to_s` on it. In fact, there are cases where there is more than one match, so `to_s` will not work for that; instead there's the `[]` operator (method really) (see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D).